# Gijgo tree open/close causing checkboxchange to run through multiple times

Tags: javascript, containers, gijgo-treeview

I have a Gijgo tree (GroupTree) which is opened in a container:

```
<button id="selectGroupAreas" class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="selectGroupAreas()"> Group Areas</button> 

function selectPRDAreas() {

        //if group tree doesn't exist yet create it. (This run once- OK)
        if (GroupTree == null) {
            GroupTree = $('#groupTree').tree({ //Gijgo tree
                primaryKey: 'id',
                uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
                dataSource: groupMenu,
                selectionType: 'multiple',
                checkboxes: true
            });
        }

        if (GroupAreaContainerDialogOpen == false) {
            $("#GroupAreaContainer").show();
            GroupAreaContainerDialogOpen = true;
            $("#GroupAreaContainer").dialog({
                draggable: true, //TODO to ensure that this stays in the page somehow?
                closed: function () {
                    GroupAreaContainerDialogOpen = false;
                }
            });
                                            
            GroupTree.on('checkboxChange', function (e, $node, record, state) {
                console.log("record.txt is " + record.text);
                //do stuff
            }
        }       

    else if (GroupAreaContainerDialogOpen == true) {
        $("#GroupAreaContainer").dialog("close");
        GroupAreaContainerDialogOpen = false;
    }
```

}

When I select the button selectGroupAreas it opens the container that contains the GroupTree. The first time this is fine, but if i open and close the container it seems that GroupTree loops through the number of times that the button has been selected.

```
So example console output looks like this:
First button press, open container, select record ABC
record.text is ABC
Close container
Open Container, select record ABC
record.text is ABC
record.text is ABC
Close container
Open Container, select record ABC
record.text is ABC
record.text is ABC
record.text is ABC
etc...
```

Open container 3 times, record.text is ABC is displayed 3 times, open 8 times record.text is ABC is 8 times.    I only want it to loop around once as it is causing problems when it is performed multiple times. This window needs be open and closed numerous times without looping through the GroupTree numerous times everytime.

Any ideas.

Thank you very much